# Pronunciation of words ending in "sten"

Tags: pronunciation

I know seven words ending in "sten" : 
chasten, christen, fasten, glisten, hasten, listen, moisten

All of them are pronounced without the sound "t". Is there some rule that explains this? Are there some other situations when "st" is pronounced as just "s"?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [tungsten](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tungsten) *is* pronounced with a t.

Comment: **Often** is another word where the **t** does not always get pronounced, this happens more frequently than is convenient in English, which is a reason the language is not easy to learn

Comment: Glorfindel, thanks indeed you are right. Maybe this exception is explained by the fact that tungsten is a noun...

Comment: @Glorfindel In *tungsten*, the second syllable is "sten", while in the question examples it is *ten*.

Comment: Note that moisten, fasten, hasten (and possibly christen?) have root words that end with the spoken 't' sound (moist, fast, haste, (possibly Christ?). The others (chasten, glisten, listen) don't - well not in common usage anyway.

Comment: List of **st** words with silent **t** is [here](http://www.spellzone.com/word_lists/list.cfm?wordlist=337)

Comment: Peter, many thanks! I've never heard of this resource, it looks very usefull

Comment: @brendan *chasten* comes from *chaste* and *listen* comes from *list* (as in the verb meaning "to lean").

Comment: @era - I know about chaste, but note that I said "...not in common usage" as it's not usually used that way.  I think you would agree that the majority of English speakers would not be aware of a link between "list" and "listen".

Answer (score 2):

If a syllable ends with "s", and the next syllable is "t" plus schwa plus L or N, the resulting "st" is reduced to just /s/.

e.g.

> moisten, whistle, thistle, hasten, fasten, christening, glisten, ...

This rules out tungsten, because its syllables are tung-sten and not tungs-ten.